What are the Vagrant limitations for VMware disks with snapshots?
The docs are a bit cryptic about this:

If snapshots exist for a VM, disk functionality will be limited.

What limitations does Vagrant impose exactly on a VMware VM that has snapshots?

FWTW, there's a one-person 'discussion' on the Vagrant forum suggesting that VMs produced by vagrant are not easy to load straight up in VMware thereafter. (They probably lack some stuff injected by vagrant on startup.) However, that's not related to snapshots.

"Vagrant will return an error for any actions that are limited due to the existence of snapshots." - You will have to load the VM in Vagrant to determine what actions are limited.
